# Артефакты при анимации в SVG

Tags: svg, артефакты

Есть некая группа `g` и внутрь я сгенерировал на javascript кучу эллипсов и потом анимировал в css обычным смещением по оси Y

Это не проблема но остаются какие то полоски

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let ocum = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  ocum += `<ellipse cx="300" cy="0" rx="200" ry="50" />`;
}
wrapper.innerHTML = ocum;
wrapper.querySelectorAll("ellipse").forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.setAttribute("cy", `${i}`);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  transform-origin: 300px 100px;
  transform: rotateX(140deg);
  animation: move 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(140deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-50px) rotateX(140deg);
  }
}

.wrapper ellipse {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.wrapper ellipse:last-child {
  fill: #1212e3;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 400" id="svg" width="500">
  <g class="wrapper"></g>
</svg>
```

**Есть ли способ избавиться от этих полосок ?**

Comment: этот косяк видно только в webkit в gecko нету

Comment: в Chrome не вижу артефактов. Но, генерить таким образом, кажется не совсем правильно, имхо.

Comment: @UModeL а каким образом генерить правильно ? createElementNS ? шаблонные выражения облегчают жизнь но вопрос не javascript

Comment: нет. В принципе такая фигура - это два эллипса и прямоугольник.

Comment: браузеру проще рендерить три элемента, чем 50.

Comment: Поддерживаю, UModeL  если это принципиально по скорости, то лучше, сбросить это в canvas - Иначе ваша анимация будет не хило так греть проц ноутов

Comment: @UModeL такие же полоски остаются https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JjEmdxw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Избавиться от данных артефактов возможно, если не "распирать" изображения в границы *viewBox*, а оставлять расстояние, минимум в 1px.

Ну и чуть снизить нагрузку на рендер, уменьшив количество одновременно анимируемых элементов:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let ocum = `
  <ellipse cx="300" cy="1" rx="200" ry="50" />
  <rect x="100" y="0" width="400" height="50" />
  <ellipse cx="300" cy="49" rx="200" ry="50" />`;

wrapper.innerHTML = ocum;
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.wrapper {
  transform-origin: 300px 100px;
  transform: translateY(0) rotateX(140deg);
  animation: move 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% { transform: translateY(-50px) rotateX(140deg); }
}

.wrapper ellipse, .wrapper rect { fill: blue; }
.wrapper ellipse:last-child { fill: #1212e3; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 400" id="svg" width="500">
  <g class="wrapper"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: я так тоже делал - смотри - сбоку тоже есть

Comment: всё таки лиса самый лучший браузер

Comment: @MaximLensky: я в Chrome - добавил по пикселю и пропали полоски. Может от железа зависит?

Comment: железо у меня нормальное - ксеон и 32 ггб озу - скорее всего фиг знает

Comment: в threejs это вообще не проблема в svg это вообще проблема ..антиальясинг и прочее ...

Comment: @MaximLensky: скорость и объёмы ни при чём. Архитектура, алгоритмы и драйвера видюхи вносят коррективы - моделей много и оптимизация затруднительна.

Comment: ну у меня модель 200мгб загружаются за 3с если так понятнее

Comment: чёрт с ним куплю iMac с топовым железом ...но не уверен что другие пользователи будут иметь такой же аппарат

Comment: @MaximLensky: iMac не панацея - забудут разрабы циферку дописать, и ты свой iMac об колено поломаешь ;-)